# Users become invisible in users category when i remove the tick from the boolean field button

Tags: python, django, web

When i remove the thick from the 'Referans Kodu Doğrulaması', users become unvisible in admin panel. I've tried almost every parameters of BooleanField but i couldn't change the situation. I thought former migrations result it altough i changed it too but nothing changed.

```py
# admin.py

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    actions = [ban_users]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'profession', 'phonenumber', 'birthdate', 'search_history')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser','is_email_verified', 'is_completed_referance_signup', 'newsletter_subscription', 'referencecode' , 
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined','NumberOfEdits','Newsletterlog')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','profession','phonenumber', 'is_staff','date_joined', 'NumberOfEdits')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
    readonly_fields = ('NumberOfEdits','Newsletterlog')

# models.py

class User(AbstractUser): 
    """User model."""
    username = None
    referencecode = 
    models.ForeignKey('ReferenceCode',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, 
    verbose_name='Referans Kodu', blank=True , error_messages={'invalid':"Geçersiz referans kodu."})
    is_completed_referance_signup = models.BooleanField(verbose_name= 'Referans Kodu Doğrulaması' , blank = True , default = False )
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='E-Posta Adresi', unique=True)
    profession = models.ForeignKey('Profession',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, verbose_name='Meslek')
    birthdate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name= 'E-Posta Doğrulaması', default=False)
    phonenumber = models.CharField('Cep Telefonu Numarası',max_length=20 , blank=True, null=True)
    newsletter_subscription = models.BooleanField(verbose_name= 'E-Posta Haber Aboneliği', default=False)
    search_history = models.ManyToManyField(SearchHistory, blank=True, verbose_name="Arama Geçmişi")
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        if self.first_name == '' and self.last_name == '':
            return self.email
        return self.first_name +" " + self.last_name

    def save(self, is_admin_edit = False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            if not get_user_model().objects.get(pk=self.pk).newsletter_subscription == self.newsletter_subscription:
                nll  = NewsletterLog()
                nll.user = self
                nll.newsletter_subscription = self.newsletter_subscription
                if is_admin_edit:
                    nll.is_admin_edit = True
                nll.save()
            super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            if self.newsletter_subscription:
                nll  = NewsletterLog()
                nll.user = self
                nll.newsletter_subscription = self.newsletter_subscription
                if is_admin_edit:
                    nll.is_admin_edit = True
                nll.save()
```

Comment: Please post the code as text rather than an image grab so that others can use it.

Comment: Could you repost the image of your admin menu - apologies, I edited that out. If the items are 'blank', it might mean that the `__str__` method of your custom user class is returning a blank string.